# Are there memory security levels in .NET interop?

Tags: c#, interop, nunit, unmanaged

I have a quite strange problem:

I am testing several function calls to a unmanaged C dll with NUnit. The odd thing is, the test fails when it runs normally, but when i run it with the debugger (even with no break point) it passes fine.

So, has the debugger a wider memory access as the plain NUnit application?

i have isolated the call which fails. its passing back a char pointer to a string, which the marshaller should convert to a C# string. the C side looks like this:

```
#define get_symbol(a) ((a).a_w.w_symbol->s_name)
EXTERN char *atom_get_symbol(t_atom *a);

...

char *atom_get_symbol(t_atom *a) {
  return get_symbol(*a);
}
```

and the C# code:

```
[DllImport("csharp.dll", EntryPoint="atom_get_symbol")]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
private static extern string atom_get_symbol(IntPtr a);
```

the pointer which is returned from c is quite deep inside the code and part of a list. so do i just miss some security setting?

EDIT: here is the exception i get:

System.AccessViolationException : (translated to english:) there was an attempt to read or write protected memory. this might be an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CoTaskMemFree(IntPtr ptr)
at ....atom_get_symbol(IntPtr a)
```

SOLUTION:

the problem was, that the marshaller wanted to free the memory which was part of a C struct. but it sould just make a copy of the string and leave the memory as is:

```
[DllImport("csharp.dll", EntryPoint="atom_get_symbol")]
private static extern IntPtr atom_get_symbol(IntPtr a);
```

and then in the code get a copy of the string with:

```
var string = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(atom_get_symbol(ptrToStruct));
```

great!

Comment: i get an exception which states that there is an attempt to read or write protected memory when C# calls the atom_get_symbol. i checked the IntPtr argument which is passed as argument and it has a valid value. when i use the same IntPtr to the list to return a float from the C code, it works fine. so its only a problem when it should return a string...

Comment: How are you allocating the IntPtr you're passing from managed code through atom_get_symbol?

Comment: i get the IntPtr directly from the C code from another unmanaged call.

Comment: If you don't get an exception, that doesn't necessary mean your code works correctly. It's quite possible to deference an invalid pointer without getting an exception.

Comment: Where does that `IntPtr` get freed?  On the managed or unmanaged side?  Is it memory from the heap or elsewhere?

Comment: ok, but with the debugger the test passes and it also checks the returned string to be valid and whether it has the correct value. when i step through it i can also see that the string is correct. it only fails when i run the test normally.

Comment: @JeffMercado the IntPtr is a reference to a C vector with holds instances of an internal type t_atom and it should only be freed from the C code. i would say its on the heap, but i am not so familiar with the C code to know that exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will always cause a crash on Vista and up, how you avoided it at all isn't very clear.  The stack trace tells the tale, the pinvoke marshaller is trying to release the string buffer that was allocated for the string.  It always uses CoTaskMemFree() to do so, the only reasonable guess at an allocator that might have been used to allocate the memory for the string.  But that rarely works out well, C or C++ code almost always uses the CRT's private heap.  This doesn't crash on XP, it has a much more forgiving memory manager.  Which produces undiagnosable memory leaks.

Notable is that the C declaration doesn't give much promise that you can pinvoke the function, it doesn't return a `const char*`.  The only hope you have is to declare the return type as IntPtr instead of string so the pinvoke marshaller doesn't try to release the pointed-to memory.  You'll need to use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() to convert the returned IntPtr to a string.

You'll need to test the heck out of it, call the function a billion times to ensure that you don't leak memory.  If that test crashes with an OutOfMemoryException then you have a big problem.  The only alternative then is to write a wrapper in the C++/CLI language and make sure that it uses the exact same version of the CRT as the native code so that they both use the same heap.  Which is tricky and impossible if you don't have the source code.  This function is just plain difficult to call from any language, including C.  It should have been declared as `int atom_get_symbol(t_atom* a, char* buf, size_t buflen)` so it can be called with a buffer that's allocated by the client code.

Comment: The function is just a chain of indirection, what memory can it allocate?

Comment: A C string requires memory to store the characters.  It is technically possible that the C code manages that memory itself but then it should have returned a const char* to prevent client code from messing with the string.  And take the considerable risk that the client code stores the pointer and uses it *after* the C code has released memory.  The only safe way is to return a copy of the string.  In memory that needs to be released by the caller.

Comment: The string is a member of a struct, so probably the code that destroys the struct handles freeing the string. Returning a copy of the string isn't neccesery, the caller can copy the string (given that the documentation specifies the lifetime of the string).

Comment: You are right, I missed the macro.  Well, IntPtr should work then as long as it is not stored.

Comment: confirmed! private static extern IntPtr atom_get_symbol(IntPtr a); with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr) works! great insight in your answer as well, thank you! so the problem was, that the marshaller wanted to free the memory of the string which was part of the struct...